# Серверный сокет без ожидания клиента

Tags: java, сокеты

Не могу найти примеры серверного сокета, где нету ожидания клиента, то есть без accept(). Как можно сделать без выполнения этого метода и сделать проверку на подключение клиента?

```
public void runServer() {
    int port = 3000;
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Got a client! " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        String line = null;
        while(true) {
            line = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Input line : " + line);
            System.out.print("Sending back... ");
            out.writeUTF(line);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
    } catch(Exception x) {
        System.out.print("Lost Connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: accept нужен в любом случае. Можно сделать многопоточное приложение. И уже в потоках ожидать клиентов.

Comment: Вот, думаю нашёл, что Вы хотите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553380/waiting-for-serversocket-accept-to-put-socket-into-listen-mode

Comment: Без accept() может быть только DatagramSocket, но с ним не сделаешь проверку подключения, так как подключений никаких быть не может. Можно использовать NIO и неблокирующийся accept(). Чего именно вы хотите?

Comment: Хочу что-бы параллельно с подключением клиентов происходили другие процессы.